# org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I am deploying application with jdk 21 and getting this exception while in another pc it is working properly but in another i am getting this exception

09:06:56,080 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
09:06:56,080 ERROR [org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Failed to instantiate class com.imageinfo.eclear.v2.utils.eclear_evtproclistener: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//com.imageinfo.eclear.configuration.MyConfigure.getSessionFactoryInstance(MyConfigure.java:44)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//com.imageinfo.eclear.v2.utils.eclear_evtproclistener.(eclear_evtproclistener.java:25)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:304)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:725)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Configuration.getInstance(Configuration.java:421)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Configuration.addListener(Configuration.java:376)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parseListener(ConfigParser.java:288)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:332)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:302)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.WebManager.(WebManager.java:180)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.WebManager.(WebManager.java:111)
at deployment.expressClear_AUB_BaseVersion_HBR.war//org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener23.contextInitialized(HttpSessionListener23.java:141)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.